# Trouble receiving data from Twitter in R

Tags: r, authentication, twitter, oauth

I want to get data from a tweet.
But these are the errors.
Please help me get data?

by code

```
install.packages("rtweet")
library(rtweet)
# plotting and pipes - tidyverse!
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# text mining library
library(tidytext)
# whatever name you assigned to your created app
appname <- "**********"
## api key (example below is not a real key)
key <- "**************"
## api secret (example below is not a real key)
secret <- "***********"
twitter_token <- create_token(
  app = appname,
  consumer_key = key,
  consumer_secret = secret)
rstats_tweets <- search_tweets(q = "#rstats",
                               n = 500)
```

> Error in check_twitter_oauth (): OAuth authentication error:
>   This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth () '
>
> Error in curl :: curl_fetch_memory (url, handle = handle):
>      Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10,000 milliseconds

Comment: Are you done create the app on twitter api?
If you done, please check again the app name, consumer_key, and consumer_secret For alternative, you can use the similar package like "twitteR"

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://rtweet.info/) claims:

> ### API authorization
>
> - The first time you make an API request—e.g., search_tweets(), stream_tweets(), get_followers()—a browser window will open.
> - Log in to your Twitter account.
> - Agree/authorize the rtweet application.
>
> And that’s it!

However, this did not work for me.

I had to follow the rtweet tutorial how [obtaining and using access tokens](http://rtweet.info/articles/auth.html):

```
# install from CRAN
install.packages("rtweet")
# load rtweet
library(rtweet)
```

I also had to install the `httpuv` package. This is not mentioned in the tutorial but you get a corresponding error message in R.

> Error in oauth_listener(authorize_url, is_interactive) :
>      httpuv package required to capture OAuth credentials.

```
install.packages("httpuv")
```

Then Create your Twitter app with the correct Callback URL on apps.twiter.com:

> To create a Twitter app, navigate to [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com) and create a new app by providing a Name,
>   Description, and Website of your choosing (example screenshot provided
>   below).
>   **Important In the Callback URL field, make sure to enter the following: `http://127.0.0.1:1410`**
>   Check yes if you agree and then click “Create your Twitter application”.

```
## whatever name you assigned to your created app
appname <- "rtweet_token"

## api key (example below is not a real key)
key <- "XYznzPFOFZR2a39FwWKN1Jp41"

## api secret (example below is not a real key)
secret <- "CtkGEWmSevZqJuKl6HHrBxbCybxI1xGLqrD5ynPd9jG0SoHZbD"

## create token named "twitter_token"
twitter_token <- create_token(
  app = appname,
  consumer_key = key,
  consumer_secret = secret)
```

then, finally, a browser window opened after this code is executed (something like the following):

```
http://localhost:1410/?oauth_token=asdfasdfasdfaf5naw&oauth_verifier=dffasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsk9jIQxDG6
```

showing the message:

> Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R.

and now you should be good to go.

See also:

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth